# $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_n Y_n \to pZ \ \ \ \text{a.s.}$

Tags: probability-theory, almost-everywhere

I'm stuck with this exercise...

Let $\{X_n\}$, $\{Y_n\}$ r.v. bounded and independent such that
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}X_n \to p \ \ \ \text{a.s.},$$
prove that
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_n Y_n \to pZ \ \ \ \text{a.s.},$$
where $Z = \lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}Y_n$.

I suspect some things. I tried to use the Strong Law of Large Number but nothing... Also since the r.v. are bounded I tried to use Fatou theorem and the Dominated Convergence Theorem but again I could not prove the statement. Any idea?

Comment: Something is off, if the variables are bounded, the moments exist and therefore $1/n \sum_1^n X_kY_k \to E(X_1 Y_1),$ which need not be $E(X_1)E(Y_1).$ It will be in the sequences $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are  uncorrelated.

Comment: As written, this isn't true, so you'll have a hard time proving it.

Comment: As written, this is not true. For example, if $X_n$ chooses randomly between $1$ and $2$ with equal probability, and $Y_i=4/X_i,$ then $Z=3, p=3/2,$ and $pZ=\frac{9}{2}.$ But $X_iY_i=4$ for all $i.$

Comment: Just guessing, because of the use of the variable $p,$ that perhaps the $X_i$ are supposed to be $0$ and $1?$ Then, I think you only need independent and identical for only one of the sequences.

Comment: So the exercise is wrong?

Comment: I also noticed you used $p$ and $Z.$ Both $p$ and $Z$ are numbers when the random sequences $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are, each one, i.i.d. I suspect you are missing an awful lot of context in this question.

Comment: I'm not used anything. The exercise is literally that. I'm also feel that something is wrong but I do not what.

Comment: The exercise is wrong unless you assume that the sequences are uncorrelated (this is implied if you assume independence).

Comment: I think that is reasonable. Thanks I'm going to improve the exercise.

Comment: Done. I updated the exercise.